# Getting childs inside a directive Angular

Tags: angular, viewchild

I have a directive named `FooDirective` and injecting `TemplateRef` to get the template, I do have another directive named `BarDirective` which inject `ElementRef`:

```
Directive({
     selector: '[BarDirective]'
    })
  export class BarDirective{
    constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {}

Directive({
  selector: '[FooDirective]'
})
export class FooDirective{
  @ViewChild(BarDirective) pEl: BarDirective; <-- It is always undefined after AfterViewInit hook
  @ContentChild(BarDirective) pEl: BarDirective; <-- also undefined, AfterContentInit hook
  constructor(public templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) {}
```

I am using it like this:

```
@Component({template:'
<some-component>
        <div *FooDirective>
            <p BarDirective></p>
         </div>
      </some-component>
'})
export class SomeComponent{
   @ViewChild(FooDirective) foo: FooDirective <-- Ok
   @ViewChild(BarDirective) bar: BarDirective <-- undefined
}
```

How can I access `BarDirective` through `FooDirectvie` or `SomeComponent`?

I already tried `ViewChild` in `SomeComponent` which is also undefined.

Comment: Did you render the template in your `FooDirective` before trying to access the ContentChild (e.g. inside ngOnInit)? If you add it with a `*` in front, it will wrap the element you're attaching it to in an `ng-template` and it will **not** render it automatically. This way, bar would never be created.

Comment: @pascalpuetz Yes, I render the template by `<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="foo.templateRef"></ng-container>`

Comment: That sounds like you are rendering it at a completely different place then where the original foo directive is placed. This is quite uncommon. Are you certain that you are doing that in the same rendering cycle? Maybe your afterViewInit just happens too soon?